# Change a mutation value when fetching another query RTK Query?

Tags: redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

**I have a query that fetches all data, and also have a mutation that handles delete an item**

```
const {
  isFetching: isFetchingProducts,
  data: productsData,
  refetch
} = useGetProductsQuery("");
const [
  deleteProduct,
  { isSuccess: productDeleted, error: deleteProductFailed }
] = useDeleteProductMutation();
```

I'm trying to make productDeleted false when isFetchingProducts is true, we could achieve that in old redux by for example

```
case(GET_PRODUCTS) 
   isFetching: true, 
   productDeleted: false
```

**How to do that in the RTK query? thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Those two exist completely independently from each other, so there is no real way of doing that.

We will be adding a `.reset` functionality at some point in the future ([github issue here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1455)), but currently you will just have to track something like that in a local component state variable.

Comment: will be looking forward for that, and good job on rtk query , its awesome